# Ant-style pattern matching multiple file type

Tags: gradle

I am new to gradle and I have a gradle script that will produce a zip of a folder that contains media files only. How do we define a pattern that will match multiple file types (file with extension A or B or C)?

For example, let's say the folder has the following files:

```
 1. bar.jpg
 2. src/bar.gif
 3. src/bar.js
 4. bbar.swf
```

And I want to grab all media files, which can be jpg, jpeg, gif, and swf.

Currently, here's how I'm doing it right now:

```
  def mediaFilesExtension= ["**/*.gif", "**/*.jpg", "**/*.jpeg", "**/*.svg", "**/*.png", "**/*.bmp", "**/*.swf"]

  task zipImages(type:Zip) {
        arhiveName "images.zip"
        destinationDir = file("build/output")
        from "source"
        include mediaFilesExtension
  }
```

I don't like how I have to repeat `**\*` and I am sure there is a better ANT-style pattern matching that I can use for my `include`.

I tried `**/*.gif|jp?g|swf` but it doesn't work. I tried googling but didn't find any examples on this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def extensions = ["gif", "jpg", "jpeg", "svg", "png", "bmp", "swf"] as Set
include { FileTreeElement el ->
    int dotIndex = el.file.name.lastIndexOf('.')
    if (dotIndex < 0) return false
    String extension = el.file.name.substring(dotIndex + 1).toLowerCase()
    return extensions.contains(extension)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your include to this

```
include {
    return it.name.endsWith(".jpg") || it.name.endsWith(".gif") // so on
}
```